# Maven Proguard processing a library jar that other applications will depend one

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3, proguard

Here is what my build plug in stanza looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <options>
            <option>-dontshrink</option>
            <option>-dontnote</option>
            <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
            <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
            <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is what I get from execution of `mvn clean package`

`[proguard] Error: You have to specify '-keep' options for the shrinking step.`

**How do I specify the keep options for a library where I just want obfuscation?**

Comment: Cfr. [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html) > [Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html) > [Error: You have to specify '-keep' options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#keep)

Comment: this doesn't even begin to explain how to fix my problem, obviously I need to supply `-keep` options, but nothing actually gives me an example of what I need to specify in the Maven `pom.xml` file. This is just repeating what the error messages says plainly enough already. And that link has nothing to do with Maven either.

Comment: Your quoted build plug in stanza already contains <option> tags that contain ProGuard options. You can add -keep options there (obviously?). As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Maven or pom.xml indeed.

Comment: there is no documentation on what my `-keep` option should look like?

Comment: The ProGuard manual contains plenty of information (did you miss it?). Notably: ProGuard manual > Examples > A typical library.

Answer (score 6):

You must define with the `-keep` option the entry points of your application, because you can't obfuscate it. For example if your main class is obfuscated it will be renamed and you won't be able to launch it. The same for public interfaces of your APIs.